# How could I implement the push macro?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

Can someone help me understand how `push` can be implemented as a macro? The naive version below evaluates the place form twice, and does so before evaluating the element form:

```
(defmacro my-push (element place)
  `(setf ,place (cons ,element ,place)))
```

But if I try to fix this as below then I'm `setf`-ing the wrong place:

```
(defmacro my-push (element place)
   (let ((el-sym    (gensym))
         (place-sym (gensym)))
     `(let ((,el-sym    ,element)
            (,place-sym ,place))
        (setf ,place-sym (cons ,el-sym ,place-sym)))))

CL-USER> (defparameter *list* '(0 1 2 3))
*LIST*
CL-USER> (my-push 'hi *list*)
(HI 0 1 2 3)
CL-USER> *list*
(0 1 2 3)
```

How can I `setf` the correct place without evaluating twice?

Comment: Looking over the SBCL source, I see that they use the once-only macro to handle rplaca (see this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808928/understanding-how-to-implement-once-only-lisp-macro ). I would investigate rplaca for further understanding.

Comment: @PaulNathan Can you please provide the SBCL version and source location you're looking at? Because I see `(defmacro-mundanely push (obj place &environment env) ...` in `src/code/early-setf.lisp` (SBCL 1.0.58), which doesn't use `once-only`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this right seems to be a little more complicated. For instance, the code for `push` in SBCL 1.0.58 is:

```
(defmacro-mundanely push (obj place &environment env)
  #!+sb-doc
  "Takes an object and a location holding a list. Conses the object onto
  the list, returning the modified list. OBJ is evaluated before PLACE."
  (multiple-value-bind (dummies vals newval setter getter)
      (sb!xc:get-setf-expansion place env)
    (let ((g (gensym)))
      `(let* ((,g ,obj)
              ,@(mapcar #'list dummies vals)
              (,(car newval) (cons ,g ,getter))
              ,@(cdr newval))
         ,setter))))
```

So reading the documentation on [get-setf-expansion](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get_se.htm) seems to be useful.

For the record, the generated code looks quite nice:

Pushing into a symbol:

```
(push 1 symbol)
```

expands into

```
(LET* ((#:G906 1) (#:NEW905 (CONS #:G906 SYMBOL)))
  (SETQ SYMBOL #:NEW905))
```

Pushing into a SETF-able function (assuming `symbol` points to a list of lists):

```
(push 1 (first symbol))
```

expands into

```
(LET* ((#:G909 1)
       (#:SYMBOL908 SYMBOL)
       (#:NEW907 (CONS #:G909 (FIRST #:SYMBOL908))))
  (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA #:SYMBOL908 #:NEW907))
```

So unless you take some time to study `setf`, [setf expansions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_aab.htm) and company, this looks rather arcane (it may still look so even after studying them). The 'Generalized Variables' chapter in [OnLisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) may be useful too.

Hint: if you compile your own SBCL (not that hard), pass the `--fancy` argument to `make.sh`. This way you'll be able to quickly see the definitions of functions/macros inside SBCL (for instance, with <kbd>M-.</kbd> inside Emacs+SLIME). Obviously, don't delete those sources (you can run `clean.sh` after `install.sh`, to save 90% of the space).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at how the existing one (in SBCL, at least) does things, I see:

```
* (macroexpand-1 '(push 1 *foo*))

(LET* ((#:G823 1) (#:NEW822 (CONS #:G823 *FOO*)))
  (SETQ *FOO* #:NEW822))
T
```

So, I imagine, mixing in a combination of your version and what this generates, one might do:

```
(defmacro my-push (element place)
   (let ((el-sym  (gensym))
         (new-sym (gensym "NEW")))
     `(let* ((,el-sym  ,element)
             (,new-sym (cons ,el-sym ,place)))
        (setq ,place ,new-sym)))))
```

A few observations:

1. This seems to work with either `setq` or `setf`.  Depending on what problem you're actually trying to solve (I presume re-writing `push` isn't the actual end goal), you may favor one or the other.
2. Note that `place` does still get evaluated twice... though it does at least do so only after evaluating `element`.  Is the double evaluation something you actually need to avoid?  (Given that the built-in `push` doesn't, I'm left wondering if/how you'd be able to... though I'm writing this up before spending terribly much time thinking about it.)  Given that it's something that needs to evaluate as a "[place](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place)", perhaps this is normal?
3. Using `let*` instead of `let` allows us to use `,el-sym` in the setting of `,new-sym`.  This moves where the `cons` happens, such that it's evaluated in the first evaluation of `,place`, and after the evaluation of `,element`.  Perhaps this gets you what you need, with respect to evaluation ordering?
4. I think the biggest problem with your second version is that your `setf` really does need to operate on the symbol passed in, not on a `gensym` symbol.

Hopefully this helps...  (I'm still somewhat new to all this myself, so I'm making some guesses here.)

Comment: Interesting. The HyperSpec says the place form is only evaluated once, but it looks like SBCL knows that getting the value from a symbol twice is harmless. For a place form with a possible side effect it does: CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(push 4 (my-list-func)))
(LET* ((#:G31 4) (#:G30 (CONS #:G31 (MY-LIST-FUNC))))
  #:G30
  (FUNCALL #'(SETF MY-LIST-FUNC) #:G30)). Does this form of SETF avoid a second evaluation somehow?

Comment: When I actually run the above I get "Undefined function (SETF MY-LIST-FUNC)". Looks like the double evaluation problem is avoided by disallowing place forms which are not SETF-able on their own. Makes sense.