# once-only lisp macro, yet another implementation

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I am trying to learn Lisp from Peter Seibel's book "Practical Common Lisp". In [chapter 8 : "Macros: Defining your own"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html), I came across this once-only macro. At the bottom of that page, an implementation is given.

I tried implementing my own macro for the same purpose earlier, but it had a bug, as pointed out at [once-only lisp macro, is my implementation correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232156/once-only-lisp-macro-is-my-implementation-correct).

This time I have done another alternate implementation, hopefully fixing that bug. I would like to know if my implementation is correct this time around ?

```
(defmacro my-once-only ((&rest args) &rest body)
  (let
    ((gensyms (loop for x in args collect (gensym))))

    `(let
      (,@(loop for g in gensyms for x in args collect `(,g ,x))
       ,@(loop for x in args collect `(,x (gensym))))

      `(let
         ,`(,,@(loop for x in args for g in gensyms collect ``(,,x ,,g)))

         ,,@body))))
```

Comment: If the code is (apparently) working, then this would be better for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  I've flagged for migration.

Comment: Ok, tnx. Wasnt aware of Code Review, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: No worries;  it's a newer site.  Since this question doesn't have a specific technical problem, it's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow, but it's a good fit for Code Review.  I'd rather see it stay open and migrated than closed altogether.